# Is it a good idea to invoke lambda from other lambda in AWS lambda service?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, invoke

I have couple of lambda functions and all of these functions have one function common. Since it is common and most of the code is in that common function. So it is logical to consider separate lambda function for that particular function.

But It discouraged me when i think about cost prospective. I mean, invoking one lambda will automatically invoke another lambda. So one event will hire two different resources. and it does not seems me cost effective. Is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done all the time. I've had Lambdas running on a schedule be deterministic in which additional Lambdas to invoke based on various factors.

However, you have to keep in mind what that common "function" is doing and how that impacts not only cost but, performance.

There's two main mindsets when you architect your serverless app or the serverless components within an app. You can think of AWS Lambda, Azure Functions, Google Cloud Functions, etc. as a "one function" solution truly putting the "micro" in microservice. Or you can use a Lambda as a logical group of functions (what I would still consider "one function...of your app") where you'd have multiple within a single Lambda. Both are completely valid approaches and one will probably result in less headaches while debugging =)

If you have a common function for several Lambdas you may want to consider handling this in your code before reaching for another Lambda. By that I mean something like packages or libraries. For example with Node.js, you'd just use NPM to import in that common function so you can maintain it from one place and simply update anything relying on it as needed.

Try not to take "cloud function" so literally and split every single function into a new Lambda.

Keep in mind that there's a minimum charge for Lambda because it rounds up to the nearest 100ms. So if you're calling some common function that actually runs really fast... I wouldn't separate it out into a new Lambda. You're going to pay more but, also your performance will be hindered too.

Your mileage will vary like anything else. Cloud functions kinda give us a whole new dimension to think about. While they are super convenient, they can actually degrade performance and increase costs if not carefully planned.