# Is it a good idea to call one AWS Lambda from another with an APIGatewayProxyRequest?

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This question is inspired by this other: [Is it a good idea to invoke lambda from other lambda in AWS lambda service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964429/is-it-a-good-idea-to-invoke-lambda-from-other-lambda-in-aws-lambda-service)

I am using netcoreapp3.1 and C# to develop lambda.

I have one lambda A that accepts HTTP requests from API Gateway. I am using the dotnet template `serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI` as per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/running-serverless-asp-net-core-web-apis-with-amazon-lambda where my lambda function reacts to invokations as if it was a web api.

I have another lambda B that also gets invoked by API Gateway, only this time it gets websocket events (CONNECT, DISCONNECT, MESSAGE).

I am thinking of having lambda B invoking lambda A synchronously.

The flow would be like this: API Gateway > Lambda B > Lambda A

I have here a dilemma:

- Is it a **good idea to invoke directly Lambda A from Lambda B?**
- Or is it **better to have Lambda B send an http request to API Gateway** and leave the gateway do its thing invoking Lambda A?
- Or should I forget about exposing Lambda A functionality as "http" and **have a single entry point in Lambda A that accepts ANY payload so that Lambda B can invoke it with a custom message?**

Cost and performance wise I guess there is no much difference, but invoking Lambda A from Lambda B seems "easier" as the only thing I really need is to know the name of the function.

Here comes my attempt to do that, I use the

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(
    APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayProxyRequest, 
    ILambdaContext context)
{
    context.Logger.LogLine("Get Request\n");
    var isWebSocketRequest = apiGatewayProxyRequest.HttpMethod is null;
    if (!isWebSocketRequest)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"Received Http method {apiGatewayProxyRequest.HttpMethod}, not a valid websocket event");
    }

    var result = await ProcessWebsocketEvent(apiGatewayProxyRequest, context.Logger);
    return result;
}

private async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> ProcessWebsocketEvent(APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaLogger logger)
{
    var eventType = apiGatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext.EventType;
    string body = eventType;
    if ("CONNECT" == eventType)
    {
        body += $", connection={apiGatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext.ConnectionId}";
    }
    else if ("DISCONNECT" == eventType)
    {
        body += $", connection={apiGatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext.ConnectionId}";
    }
    else if ("MESSAGE" == eventType)
    {
        body += $", body={apiGatewayProxyRequest.Body}";
    }

    logger.LogLine("Creating amazon lambda client..");
    using var lambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest3);
    var payload =
        new
        {
            Foo = "bar",
            Bar = "foo"
        };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
    logger.LogLine($"With payload {payload}");
    var request =
        new InvokeRequest
        {
            FunctionName = "lambda-dotnet-webapi-function",
            Payload = json
        };
    
    var responseInvoke = await lambdaClient.InvokeAsync(request);
    using var stream = new StreamReader(responseInvoke.Payload);
    var responsePayload = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();

    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Body = responsePayload,
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Content-Type", "text/plain"}}
    };
    return response;
}
```

First thing I noticed. If I have a 3 seconds timeout, it times out. I have to increase it.
If I increase it to 10 seconds I am able to get an invocation as the invoke request's payload is not "correct"

```
{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-Type":"text/plain"},"body":"{\n  \"errorType\": \"NullReferenceException\",\n  \"errorMessage\": \"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\",\n  \"stackTrace\": [\n    \"at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)\",\n    \"at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)\",\n    \"at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )\"\n  ]\n}\n","isBase64Encoded":false}
```

The Lambda A runs for 800ms
The Lambda B runs for 9000ms (9 seconds, a lot..)

This brings me to another question. **If this is an acceptable approach, how can I send the request as if Lambda B was a "proxy"?**

*I am thinking of invoking Lambda A in an http-ish way, mainly because I really like the library https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer which allows my Lambda to be implemented as a standard aspNet web api, read appsettings, dependency injection, test with test server, etc.*

Looking at Lambda A logs I can see the following warning

```
[Warning] Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction: Request does not contain domain name information but is derived from APIGatewayProxyFunction.
```

and the exception that I am getting as the response in Lambda B:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.: NullReferenceException
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

Comment: If you do not need response from Lambda A then maybe this would work? Lambda B => SQS => Lambda A.

Comment: I need response. It has to be synchronous, that's why I wanted to have a request/response payload and treat it asa proxy request or similar. There's gonna be some inevitable coupling there unless I put lambda A and lambda B together and make it deal with more things in the same function, which seems not ideal either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are connecting to from lambda B and lambda A needs to warm up this coulf take a few seconds (at least 3) so if your timeout on lambda B is 3 seconds you receives a timeout

A solution for this is mantain in warm up your lambda A, maybe with a ping operation, but this implicates that you will have a lambda up most of time

Othe thing

could you add

InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse,

to InvokeRequest

Comment: I'm not too concerned about response time at the moment as you mentioned it's due to lambda not being warmed. My concern is what's the best way to trigger lambda A and whether to do so directly or through api gateway. Thanks for the invocation type, I'll explore that

Comment: Maybe is better to call the gateway, thinking in the future you can change your lambda by an aplication in ECS or EC2 resources, using your API over an homologed protocol (REST),  So in this moment is easier to call the lambda but if you have to change where your application its, you will have to change more things, I think  maybe you need to consider if your application will change alot in the time or you will not touch that in alot of time is a trade off I think